# Shell and text manipulation: marking the ends of sentences and controlling space between paragraphs

Tags: bash, shell, unix

After processing it should be like

```
  I need to go london, after i reach the; Uk.

  But i need five hours? To reach it.
```

But I get:

```
 I need to go london, after i reach the; Uk.
 .
 .
 .
 But i need five hours? To reach it.
```

It works but it adds a dot at the first line but I need to add dot just at end of paragraph that has no dot. Also, if I have more than one blank line, or if there is no blank line, between paragraphs, I need to ensure exactly one blank line between paragraphs.

How do I deal with these issues?

Comment: See also [Shell: What does the 'number of sentences' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065231/shell-what-the-means-of-number-of-sentence) — paraphrased.

Comment: What constitutes the start of a paragraph when there is no blank line between them?  Is it that there text does not start in column 1 (there are blanks there instead)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove blank lines between paragraphs with `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/\n\n+/,"\n\n");printf $0}' RS="^$" file
```

and to avoid dots at beginning of lines, you could change your last sed command to:

```
/\(^$\)\|\([!?;.,]\s*$\)/! s/\s*$/.&/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '{if(NR == 1) print $0"\n"; else if($1 != ".") print $0}' file
```

You could also `read` from the file and use `echo -e` to double space the lines:

```
n=0
while read f _ ; do
    ((n++))
    if [[ $f != . ]]; then
        if [ $n -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "$f\n"
        else
            echo -e "\n$f"
        fi
    fi
done < file
```