# shell: What the means of number of sentence

Tags: shell, unix

I need to count number of sentences and paragraphs  but I do not understand how to do this from a text file.

I can count the number of lines and words using the `wc` command but I do not understand the meaning of sentence and paragraph in text file. Is there any command in shell do this?

Here's how we count number of words and lines in a text file:

```
wc -w filename

wc -l filename
```

For sentences and paragraphs, here is what I tried:

```
 grep -c \\. #to count number of sentences.
 grep -o [.'\n'] #to count number of paragraph.
```

I do not understand how to count number of sentences and paragraphs in a text file.

Any ideas will be helpful.

for example:

Main article: SSID#Security of SSID hiding.

A simple but ineffective method to attempt to secure a wireless network is SSID     (Service Set Identifier).[12][13] This provides very little protection against anything    but the most casual intrusion efforts...

2 paragraph,and 3 sentence.

Comment: a sentence ends with a period `.` so just count those making sure to filter out stuff like `...` A paragraph is a chunk of text surrounded by empty lines.

Comment: is there any command in shell doing this.

Comment: yes, ex. `grep` and `awk`

Comment: i know these commands, but how i used them to count.

Comment: `grep -o 'regexp' | wc -l` to count

Comment: i know this,but what regular expression should i use ,i try alot of them but it does not work.

Comment: @user3185416: Please copy everything you've tried already to your question and explain what didn't work and why.

Comment: What about `!` and `?` to end sentences? I believe they count too!  And it gets trickier when you have "quoted question?" Etc. (Oh, did the `.` in `Mr. Leffler` end a sentence?)  Sentences are fickle.  Paragraphs are generally chunks of text surrounded by blank lines (or the beginning or end of file)…unless you're working with text in a markup (or markdown) language.  It comes down to 'what was the definition of sentence and paragraph that the person setting the homework wanted you to use'.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, its project i work on it,there is no any definition of sentence and paragraph its in general.

Comment: That's useful; it means you can make a definition that suits you and makes life easy for you.  How often are you going to be doing this? Are you going to be publishing research papers on the breakdown of documents in paragraphs and sentences (in which case you're going to need to deal with most of the issues I raised), or is it for casual use (in which case, you can be more relaxed about it all and a few mistakes won't matter much).  Hopefully, it is nearer the latter than the former.  It will probably work out that as long as you can justify your decisions, any reasonable answer can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first approximation can be obtained under the assumptions that:

1. Sentences end with a period and periods are only used for that (no
   decimal numbers, no ellipsis, etc.)
2. Paragraphs are separated with exactly one empty line

(Of course those are not met in reality but it should get you started)

```
grep -oc \\.
```

will count the number of sentences, and

```
grep -c "^$"
```

will count the number of paragraphs. If your text is strongly formatted you may get to something that works, otherwise, you could consider using Natural Language Processing tools such as [NLTK](http://nltk.org/).

Comment: @user3185416: Please explain what you tried with what input, what result you got, what you think the correct result is, and why the result you got is wrong.

Comment: grep -c counts matching lines. Will not work with multiple periods on one line, use `grep -o`

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of sentences, you could count the number of peroids, question marks, and exclamation points.  But then you run into the problem of an ellipsis (...). I suppose you could only count it if it has whitespace afterwards.

Paragraphs are another matter.  Are they indented?  How, with a tab?  Then count them.

The big question is 'What is the delimiter between sentences and paragraphs?'

When you know that, define the delimiter regex, and count how many are in the file using the tool of your choice.